# Potential Difference

Tags: electricity, potential

Ohm's law:
$$V=IR$$

Here $I$ is the current in the circuit, which is equal to charge flowing per unit time.

$R$ is the resistance offered. $V$ is potential difference.

What's the physical significance of potential difference in a circuit?
I mean, how does it even arise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potential difference (or voltage) is equivalent to a pressure difference in a pipe system of water.

- If there is equal pressure at two points, then no water has any reason to move. If there is a difference, water flows (is pushed) towards lower pressure.
- Similarly, charges will want to move towards the point of lowest possible potential. The larger the potential difference, the larger the "pressure" is pushing these charges.

[Here's something for the intuition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/161701/4962).

The origin of potential is quite straight forward:

- Charge of equal sign repels each other. If you move many electrons, for example, together they will push on each other to move away.
- Imagine having much charge in one end of a wire and less charge in the other end. Then the repulsion is larger where there is more charge, and it will be pushed to the other end - it will as well be repelled from this other end, but *less*.

This potential difference is the sole reason that any current is flowing at all.